# vectorizing an optimization in python

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, vectorization

I am trying to vectorize an optimization (root finding) problem where I need to find roots of an integral. I haven't found any good integration functions that work with vectorization so I coded up a tradezoidal approach to integration. The following code is an attempt to vectorize the roots (for each d there is a different root) finding problem for an input **array** **d** of length **N=300000** instead of using a loop for different values of **d**.

```
from scipy import optimize as op
import numpy as np

N=300000
d=np.random.rand(N)

def f(z): # vectorized version- depends on d as well
    return ((1-2*z)*np.exp(-d[:,None]/z))/(((1-z)**(2+d[:,None]))*(z**(2-d[:,None])))

def trap(func,start,end,num): #trapezoidal approach to integration
     diff=(end-start)/(num-1.0)
     g=np.arange(num)
     xlinear=diff[:,None]*g+start[:,None]
     fx=func(xlinear)
     return np.trapz(fx,xlinear)

def integral(p):
     start=np.zeros_like(p) +0.001 
     return trap(f,start,p,100)

root=op.fsolve(integral,0.75*np.ones_like(d))
```

However, the above code is throwing a memory error for me.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "H:...my_module.py", line 344, in 
    root=op.fsolve(integral,0.75*np.ones_like(a)) 
  File "C:..scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 140, in fsolve
    res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)
  File "C:...scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 209, in _root_hybr
    ml, mu, epsfcn, factor, diag)
MemoryError
```

I am open to completely different approaches to do this.

Comment: At which line do you have `memory error`?

Comment: what is `a`? Its not defined in your code.

Comment: sorry, that was d. edited

Comment: Does it work for a smaller problem?  N of 300, 1000?

Comment: yes it does. Although I had to change d= np.ones_like(np.arange(N)) instead of random to get reasonable convergence.

Comment: Why don't you use scipy.integrate.trapz?

Comment: If I understand right, you build up an array of size N**2 in `f` with N=300000. How is that supposed to work?

Comment: trapz doesnt help here. I have still edited the code to incorporate trapz.